# Catching all clickable elements in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to add a `cursor:pointer` css style to all elements that have `(click)` handler defined (or have binding to click events). 
I believe that on AngularJS it was possible to define a css using `[ng-click] { ... }`, is there a similar workaround for Angular2/4?

Comment: There's an easy way to find out: Add the `(click)` handler, inspect the rendered element, and see if there are any unique attributes on the HTML.

Comment: I think it will no help, I just check my angular2 app and (click) is not appearing in DOM. So you can't do it with just simple css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** If you want to add some behavior to all elements that have `(click)` handler you can create directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[click]',
  host: {
    'style': 'cursor: pointer' // or class
  }
})
export class ClickableDirective {}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1XtAeEJaMsw0a5rsrqYT?p=preview)**

**2)** To catch all element that have `click` handler i would override `EventManager`

```
import { Injectable, Inject, NgZone }      from '@angular/core';
import { EventManager, EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class MyEventManager extends EventManager {
  constructor(@Inject(EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS) plugins: any[], private zone: NgZone) {
    super(plugins, zone);
  }

  addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
    if(eventName === 'click') {
      element.style.cursor = 'pointer'; // or add class
    }

    return super.addEventListener(element, eventName, handler);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: EventManager, useClass: MyEventManager }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BfcqGBFJPjSIBf8P2Wa1?p=preview)**

Comment: I don't see any problem with setting style `cursor:pointer` when handler is added to `click` event.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, adding `[style.cursor]="'pointer'"` to the element should do the trick.

But it might be a better to add a 'clickable' class and have the following defined in your stylesheet:

`.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}`

From what I can tell, Angular doesn't add anything onto the element's HTML when adding `(click)`.

Comment: yes, the clickable class is the obvious way. But I was looking for a way to catch all (currently) clickable elements without refactoring the project.